# A content filtering service has blocked one or more of the S[OFU] sites

Tags: discussion, filtering, blocked

LightSpeed Systems' content filter has blocked ServerFault.

This affects a tiny portion of the audience, myself included. [LightSpeed](http://www.lightspeedsystems.com/) provides network filtering for schools and government agencies. They have ServerFault [classified](http://www.lightspeedsystems.com/Archive/WebsiteDetails.aspx?domain=serverfault.com) as "Security.Proxy" because their bot found the [Proxy] tag. I submitted a request to reclassify it, but was apparently denied.

**EDIT**

As of 3pm Eastern, they've stopped blocking it. I edited the question title and body to be more generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Email us the contact information for the proxy / filtering company and we'll email them to get it reclassified.

Just hit up the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page.

Comment: done and done.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the only offenders. Cymphonix and their Network Composer appliance has content filtering built into it and it has a tendency to block things on ServerFault and SuperUser when it comes across.

And how do you know that blocking their crawlers won't immediately lead to big red flags popping up. If they see that they are being blocked, they might assume they are blocked for a reason and then will just cast a blanket block on it moreso than they already have.

Comment: True. There has to be a higher-level fix though than spamming their "flag for a moderator" tool.

Comment: @Rob:  Given what I know of filtering software, there doesn't have to be a higher-level fix.  Filtering software is an extremely blunt instrument, as currently implemented.